# Middleware in next-auth after sign-in getting infinite loop

Tags: next.js, keycloak, next-auth

Using middleware to protect all routes, after sign in getting infinite loop.

Here is my middleware:

```
export default withAuth({
  callbacks: {
    authorized: async ({ req, token }) => {
      const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname;

      if (
        pathname.startsWith("/_next") ||
        pathname === "/favicon.ico" ||
        pathname === "/__ENV.js"
      ) {
        return true;
      }

      if (token) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    },
  },
  secret: "test",
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
  },
});
```

Here is my signIn page:

```
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Signin() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session == null || session?.error === "RefreshAccessTokenError") {
      signIn("keycloak");
    } else if (status === "authenticated") {
      router.push("/");
    }
  }, [session, router, status]);

  return <div></div>;
}
```

This is how my url looks like after i sign in - `http://localhost:3000/auth/signin?callbackUrl=%2F`

What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, only jwt strategy is supported using `withAuth` middleware to protect routes. So if you're using a database strategy this is not an option for you

See [this](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/5392)

Answer (score 0):

Firsly, middleware has a hard thing for `async / await` syntax, try using legacy `Promise` to see if it helps.

Are you still on nextjs prior 12.2 (old middleware), I recommend migrating both nextjs and next-auth first. If you cannot afford migration, it's better to exclude paths before `withAuth` rather than after.
Below worked for me

```js
const EXCLUDED_PATHS = [/^\/_next/, /^\/favicon.ico$/, /^\/__ENV.js$/]
const middleware: NextMiddleware = (req, res) => {
    const { pathname } = req.nextUrl

    // Exclude some paths
    if (excludePaths.some((regexp) => regexp.test(pathname))) {
      return NextResponse.next()
    }

    return withAuth(req, {
        /*auth options*/
    })
}
export default middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. This fixed it for me:
Add this function to Signin:

```
    Signin.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    const providers = await getProviders();
    return {
        providers,
        callbackUrl: context.query.callbackUrl
    };
};
```

The above function sends a callbackUrl to the Signin function.
In your Signin function, instead of calling `signIn("keycloak");`, call `signIn("keycloak",{ callbackUrl: callbackUrl })`.
Make sure your signin function accepts the parameters. To sum it up, your signin function should be :

```
import { signIn, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function Signin({providers,callbackUrl}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (session == null || session?.error === "RefreshAccessTokenError") {
      signIn("keycloak",{ callbackUrl: callbackUrl });
    } else if (status === "authenticated") {
      router.push("/");
    }
  }, [session, router, status]);

  return <div></div>;
}
    Signin.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    const providers = await getProviders();
    return {
        providers,
        callbackUrl: context.query.callbackUrl
    };
};
```

In your case, you might not want to return providers from getInitialProps function. You can modify it accordingly.
Hope this helps!